# Java Swing HTML parser's methods not working as expected

Tags: java, html, swing, parsing

So i have a `JTextPane` with a `keyListener` and get the text from the pane after each keypress. Then I try to parse the HTML tags in order to make them different color.

```
public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag tag, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos)
{   
    if (tag == HTML.Tag.DIV)
    {
        System.out.println("tag Started:" + tag);
        tagFound = true;
    }
}

public void handleEndTag(HTML.Tag tag, int pos)
{
    if (tag == HTML.Tag.DIV)
    {
        System.out.println("tag Ended:" + tag);
        tagFound = false;
    }
}
```

Problem is that when i type

```
<div
```

Even without closing bracket it outputs

tag Started:div
tag Ended:div

Shouldn't `handleEndTag()` be called when i close a tag e.g. `</div>`, and should't `handleStartTag()` be called when i properly end the tag like this:
`<div>`

Comment: Could you post SSCCE and describe desired behaviour vs actual?

Comment: AFAIU the JVM will automatically close trailing elements.  But don't push it too far.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [JavaDoc for `DocumentParser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/DocumentParser.html) used by `HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback`

> This will message the callback for all valid tags, **as well as tags that are implied but not explicitly specified.**

You can check that

> For tags that are implied, the AttributeSet argument will have a value of Boolean.TRUE for the key HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback.IMPLIED.